# Any way to detect and disociate an HEX color code from a string in PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, json

I am making a server statistics page in PHP and one of my SQL query show the players nickname including his in-game HEX color codes.

e.g of what I get and what I actually want:

```
#FF0000Nick#00FF00name --> <span id="nickname"><span style="$color[0]">Nick</span><span style="$color[1]">name</span></span>
```

What i want to do is disociate the colors from the nickname so i can style them in css and make the nickname coloured.

Here is an idea of my actual code, it's basically a table showing other informations but I'll show you the one I use for the nickname:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

  $json = $row['data'];
  $playerDataTable = json_decode($json);

  foreach($playerDataTable as $playerData){

    $ingame_nickname = $playerData->nickname;

    echo "<div class='playerNames'";
        echo "<span>" . $forum_name . "</span>";
        echo "<span class='ingame_nickname'>" . $ingame_nickname . "</span>";
    echo "</div>";

  }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have it like "#FF0000Nick#00FF00name" to begin with?  What is the source of that data/information?  Does it really have to be like that?  Please show the actual code that you currently have.

Comment: this data comes from a server made in LUA, my codder made it into JSON, so I took the data into my PHP page, but I don't code in LUA and the only way for me to get this data is with players hex colors inside the nickname

Comment: How does the JSON look like? Is the string the only value in it? Or is the value stored as JSON in the database?

Comment: @Djebzer  Do please show the _code_ that you have too.

Comment: { "nickname": "#FF0000Nick#00FF00name" }
the JSON comes like that in the database

Comment: I'd ask "my codder" to store the values properly, ex. like `{"nameColor": "#FF0000", "name": "Nick", "nickColor": "#FF0000", "nickName": "name"}`, or at least separate the values with a certain delimiter.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/qo2gc

Comment: Hi. I'm writing this after seeing your second update/answer; again, I'd ask you not to post updates as answers, but as edits to your post. That aside, could you give us ALL way the users can set their color code/username?

Comment: @Vkfan as I showed in the in-game screenshot, that's how the player nickname is set, he can edit it anytime in the game options and put the HEX colors where ever he wants

Comment: @Djebzer so... I can have any amount of colors in my name, even one for every single character? But, every time I change the color, it influences the characters after it? eg. with My#FF0000Name#00FF00Is#0000FFVkfan you'll get *My* in white, *Name* in red, *Is* in green and *Vkfan* in blue?

Comment: @Vkfan well, basically the maximum you can get is two hex color codes due to the nickname length limit.. and yea, in-game the hex code is converted to a real color

Comment: @Djebzer i updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use regular expressions:

```php
$string = "#FF0000Nick#00FF00name";
$tokens = preg_split('/(#[A-Z0-9]{6})/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

$tokens will be an array of 1, 3, or 5 elements; element 0 will be the part of the username before the first hex code, 1 the first hex code (including '#') with 2 being the part of the text having that color, 3 the second hex code with 4 the part of the name colored like that.

If there's 1 hex code only, $tokens will only contain 3 elements. If there isn't any, $tokens will contain a single element, which is the full uncolored nickname.

```php
echo $tokens[0];
for($x = 1; $x < count($tokens); $x = $x + 2) {
    $color = $tokens[$x];
    $name_token = $tokens[$x + 1];
    echo '<span style="color:' . $color . ';">' . $name_token . '</span>';
}
```

Comment: @delboy1978uk  If you're going to say that it is "much better", you should explain why (I'm not saying it's not, but some support for that would be good)

Comment: Then please refer to my answer, which does explain it

Comment: Then your comment really isn't needed.  OP/visitors can judge each answer on their merits.  Arguing for your answer in the comments of another is poor sportsmanship :)

Comment: @delboy1978uk thanks, I'm going to integrate it in the answer

Comment: Patrick it looked like the post had been deleted but i wanted the OP to get the code so i posted it in a comment. but upon refreshing it seemed to be back so i posted my answer

Comment: Vkfan, you said you were going to 'integrate' my code into your answer

Comment: @delboy1978uk Which I did? The important part? To, you know, help op?

Comment: see my reply to Patrick in these very comments. But fix your answer, it's broken

Comment: Our answer you mean? :-P

Comment: @Vkfan ty for your answer, your code looks good, but I would like the hex colors to get styled in css in the html code to actually show the nickname in colors, how can i make it so? could you show me an exemple or help me to use it

Comment: @Djebzer I added the snippet to print the name starting from the $tokens

Comment: @Vkfan hey, sorry for the late answer, I can't find a way to make it work, whenever I echo the $token[0], $color or $name_token, nothing is showing except the $token[0] but it's still showing with the hex codes

Answer (score 0):

You should really get your coder to make decent JSON. But however, you can use regex with named capture group

```
<?php

$json = '{ "nickname": "#FF0000Nick#00FF00name" }';
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$garbledData = $data['nickname'];

// (?<firstHex>\#[A-F0-9]{6})  match and name the match 'firstHex' - look for a hash, then letters a-f or numbers 0-9, with a length of 6 characters  

// (?<name>.+) match and name the match 'name' - look for absolutely any characters, any amount

// (?<secondHex>\#[A-F0-9]{6})  match and name the match 'secondHex' - look for a hash, then letters a-f or numbers 0-9, with a length of 6 characters 

$regex = '/(?<firstHex>\#[A-F0-9]{6})(?<name>.+)(?<secondHex>\#[A-F0-9]{6})/';
preg_match($regex, $garbledData, $matches);

$firstHex = $matches['firstHex'];
$secondHex = $matches['secondHex'];
$name = $matches['name'];

echo $firstHex . "\n";
echo $secondHex . "\n";
echo $name . "\n";
```

Output:

```
#FF0000 
#00FF00 
Nick
```

Check it out here https://3v4l.org/qo2gc

Comment: I'd suggest you use preg_match_all instead of preg_match; it appeared to me op was trying to get multiple couples of color/name

Comment: i suppose he could do that?